# how to find records starting with a particular letter in numpy array

Tags: numpy

i am beginner in numpy and created the following array

```
data=np.array([("abcd",111,9666),("atchd",222,6669),("cdef",444,8756)],dtype=[("name",str,10),("roll",int),("phone",int)])
print(data[data["name"][0]=='a']["name"])
```

I am trying to print records that have name property starting with character 'a' but this is returning empty array. pl update

Comment: Accepted the answer. Was indeed helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is, that you can not index the "string-axis" of your data, since it is not part of the numpy array. To achieve the behaviour you expect, you can utilize [np.char.startswith](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.char.startswith.html) :

```
import numpy as np
data=np.array(
  [
    ("abcd",111,9666),
    ("atchd",222,6669),
    ("cdef",444,8756)
  ],
  dtype=[
    ("name",str,10),("roll",int),("phone",int)
  ]
)
print(data[np.char.startswith(data["name"], 'a')]["name"])
# ['abcd' 'atchd']
```

Note that there are also [other string operations](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/routines.char.html) supported by numpy.